# Is input's parent node itself?

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I have a DOM object `obj` of the type `<input>`, and want to get is parent node, but `obj.parentNode` gives back the same `obj`.Is this a specification of `<input>` objects? If so, what other kinds of DOM objects behave irregularly (returns anything other than its parent in an intuitive sense) like this?

**Edit** I must have done something wrong. sorry.

Comment: It works fine for me. Show your code, please.

Comment: That's impossible. The only node whose `parentNode` is equal to itself is the `document.documentElement` node.

Comment: The only way this could make sense is if you're using jQuery's `.closest()`.  It will return itself if that's what the selector matches.  For example: `<div class="test"><input id="inputtest" class="test" /></div>`, if you do `$('#inputtest').closest('.test')`, it'll return the input.

Comment: I think I am somehow testing it wrong. Thanks for help, people.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`input` behaves no differently than any other element on a page, and returning its `parentNode()` should not return the input itself. Try it out:

```
<p><input type='text' id='my_id' onfocus="alert(this.parentNode.tagName)" /></p>
```

This will `alert` "P".

I'm guessing that you're not correctly testing for the parentnode.